# Authentication Key: OneDrive for Business - Embed Spreadsheet into Webpage

Tags: excel, office365, onedrive

Long story short, I have been embedding Excel worksheets into a website I manage. For years I have been using OneDrive Personal with no issues.

I recently switched to OneDrive for Business and am unable to generate the authentication key for a particular worksheet like I could on OneDrive Personal.

As as example, the embed code would look something like this when generated from OneDrive Personal:

src="https://onedrive.live.com/embed?resid=SYB2XXX11227995A%2894681&authkey=!PTOLPNYkJscx894g

Now the embed code generated looks like the following:(https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRWyA.png)

Anyone have any ideas? I can't fathom this functionality isn't available in OneDrive for Business -- but I can't seem to determine how to generate the authentication key since switching to Business.

Trying to embed Excel Workbook from OneDrive for public viewing (no login to Office 365 required)